# chats js Цифры в оси y выдают ложные цифры

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Не знаю почему, но в один момент цифры стали некорректно работать в оси y. Пробовал добавлять лишние значение в дату помогло, но мне они не нужны
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код

```html
var weatherData = [-5, 0, 8, 12, 15, 18, 20, 18, 15, 10, 5];

    // Создание горизонтальных шкал и вертикальных шагов компрессора
    var temperatureLabels = [-30, -25, -20, -15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20]; // циферки в горизонтальной оси
    var compressorSteps = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]; // циферки в вертикальной оси


    // Создание контекста канваса
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.height);
   
    // Создание графика
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: temperatureLabels, compressorSteps,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'a',
          data: [38, 36, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 27, 25, 21],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'blue',
          tension: 0.1


        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          x: {
            ticks: {
              stepSize: 0,
            }
          },

               y: {
        ticks: {
          
          stepSize: 0,
           min: 10, // Минимальное значение на оси y
           max: 90,
           
          callback: function(value, index) {
            if (index < compressorSteps.length) {
              return compressorSteps[index] + '';
            }
            return '';
          }
        },
        min: Math.min(...compressorSteps),
        max: Math.max(...compressorSteps)
    }
  },
        interaction: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: false
        },
plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        mode: 'point',
        position: 'nearest',
        intersect: false
      },
      datalabels: {
        align: 'top', // Расположение значения над точкой
        anchor: 'center', // Центрирование значения внутри точки
        backgroundColor: 'blue', // Цвет фона значения
        borderRadius: 4, // Закругление углов фона значения
        color: 'white', // Цвет текста значения
        font: {
          weight: 'bold' // Жирный шрифт значения
        },
        formatter: function(value) {
          return value; // Форматирование значения (здесь значение остается без изменений)
        },
        offset: 2, // Отступ значения от точки
        padding: 2 // Внутренний отступ фона значения
      }
    }
  }
});
```